# Video Output by USB-C

Tags: usb-c, displayport

I'm working on a electronic design that includes USB-C and requires video output. I have read USB-C Specification and, as I understand it, the only way to get video output is by DisplayPort.

TUSB1046- DisplayPort™ ALT Mode 10 Gbps Linear Redriver

TPS65987 - USB Type-C® and USB PD Controller with Integrated Source and Sink
Power Path Supporting USB3 and Alternate Mode

TUSB7340 - USB 3.0 xHCI Host Controller

Crosspoint Switch
Researching about all this, I have created a block diagram with the components needed to get video output but I'm not sure about the connections between components. I think 2.0 USB lines don't need to be connected to TUSB1046 but they can be connected directly to TUSB7340, are they?

[image]

Comment: Where is the video data actually coming from? The TUSB7340 isn't a graphic card chip, so it has to come from somewhere else, and it is not shown on your diagram.

Comment: @dim Hi dim, my mistake. TUSB7340 is connected to PCIE Raspberry Compute Module 4 lines.

Comment: It's still not a video (DP) data. Take a look at first diagram on the TUSB1046 datasheet on the very 1st page.

Comment: Still, TUSB7340 will not generate video data by itself. The fact is is connected to the PCIE port of a Raspi will not magically make it generate video data. What is the component generating video data? The raspi will output its video on its HDMI port, not through the TUSB7340. I think you are mistaken on what your architecture should be, here.

Comment: @dim But, Is it not possible to send image by PCIE? Maybe the easy way is using HDMI Raspberry lines and send them to TUSB1046, isn't it?

Comment: If you think about it, you know what is required to "send images through PCIe": right, that's exactly what a full-featured graphic card does. The TUSB7340 isn't a graphic card: that's a USB controller, and it is much simpler. However, you could indeed get the HDMI output from the rapsberry, convert it to DisplayPort, and then feed it as the display input of the TUSB1046 mux. But overall, something tells me this project is much less trivial than you think. All those are very high-speed signals, designing a PCB with this isn't easy, you'll need several tries, and each PCB will not be cheap.

Comment: @dim Thank you for your answer, I know that this is not trivial, I'm aware of high-speed signal design more or less, but sending video is something new for me, and I'm not sure about video and USB-C transmision. 

One more time, thank you so much for you answer. If you want, copy and paste your message as answer and I can validate as answer for the question (this answer is fine for me).